# PostgreSQL: Drop a function without parameters

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql, drop

I created a function as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(value INTEGER) RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But I need to specify the parameter to drop the function as shown below:

```sql
DROP FUNCTION my_func(value INTEGER);
```

Because if not specifying the parameter as shown below:

```sql
DROP FUNCTION my_func;
```

Then, I got the error below:

> ERROR:  function name "my_func" is not unique
> HINT:  Specify the argument list to select the function unambiguously.

So, can I drop a function without parameters?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

In Postgres functions [can be overloaded](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/xfunc-overload.html), so parameters are necessary to distinguish overloaded functions. To unambiguously identify a function you can put only types of its parameters.

```
DROP FUNCTION my_func(INT);
```

Answer (score 60):

As of Postgres 10 you can drop functions by name only, as long as the names are unique to their schema.

Example:

```
drop function my_func;
```

Documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-dropfunction.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify zero or more parameters with `()` if there are multiple same name functions. *[The doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-overload.html) explains **Function Overloading**.

For example, you create 2 functions as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(value INTEGER) RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then, you can drop the 1st function with the SQL below:

```sql
DROP FUNCTION my_func();
```

Or, you can drop the 2nd function with the SQL below:

```sql
DROP FUNCTION my_func(INTEGER);
```

And, you create 2 procedures as shown below:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc() LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
END;
$$;
```

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc(value INTEGER) LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
END;
$$;
```

Then, you can drop the 1st procedure with the SQL below:

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE my_proc();
```

Or, you can drop the 2nd procedure with the SQL below:

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE my_proc(INTEGER);
```